# Remove Rows from a df using another df's variables

Tags: r

I have 2 `data.frames`. 1 is guest_list and the other event_list. I am trying to remove rows in the guest_list `if Guest_list$name == event_list$host`. I have been looking up the Remove Rows Threads on here but have not found the one that matches my inquiry.

**Here are the two `DFs`:**

```
event_list<-`data.frame(event=c('ONE','TWO','THREE'),event_type=c('A','B','C'),host=c("FAKE NAME","FAKE NAME","FAKE NAME","BOB","BOB","BOB"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

EVENT | EVENT_TYPE | HOST
ONE   |    A       | FAKE NAME
TWO   |    B       | FAKE NAME
ONE   |    A       | BOB
TWO   |    B       | BOB
```

**SECOND DF**

```
guest_list<-data.frame(name=c('FAKE NAME','JEFF JEFF','JOHN SMITH','BOB'),guests=c(3,2,2,2),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


NAME        | GUESTS
FAKE NAME   |    3      
JEFF JEFF   |    2       
JOHN SMITH  |    2       
BOB         |    2
```

**Expected result:**

```
NAME        | GUESTS     
JEFF JEFF   |    2       
JOHN SMITH  |    2
```

I wish I had some code to offer but I am only thinking if statements which I also dont think is correct.

Comment: `guest_list[!guest_list$name %in% event_list$host, ]`

Comment: I did not see that one, thanks @Ronak Shah